# $p$-Groups and the Cauchy theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Here is the definition of a $p$-group

> $p$ is prime. A $p$-group is a group $G$ such that every element has an order of a power of $p$.

So let me check my understanding, every element of $G$ has order $p^n$ for some $n$ yes? i.e. $\forall g \in G$, we have $g^n=e_G \in G$ for some $n$.

Okay, that I understand, but then the following I am unable to verify.

> If $|G|$ is finite, $G$ is a $p$-group if and only if $||G|$ is a power of $p$ by Cauchy's theorem.

Let $|G|=p^n$. Then, clearly $p|p^n$ an therefore by Cauchy, $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $p$. The other way round is more confusing for me as to how Cauchy can be applied.

That is all I can conclude from Cauchy. So the statement that "every element in $G$ has order of power $p$" seems to be far-fetched to deduce.

Can someone prove this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a $p-$group but $|G|=p^{n}m$ where $m\neq 1$ is an integer which is not divisible by $p$. There must be a prime $q$ such that $q\neq p$ and $q$ divides $m$. Cauchy Theorem now says that there exists $g\in G$ such that the order of $g$ is $q$. This is a contradiction since $G$ is a $p$-group, the order of $g$ must be $p^{k}$ for suitable $k$. We conclude $m$ must $1$ and $|G|=p^{n}$.